# Debug sudden shutdowns

Tags: electrical-power, kernel-panic, unexpected-shutdown

I have two (new)workstations showing weird symptoms: they randomly power off without any sort of warning or delay,... They just may or may not power off at any given time and reboot after that.

The OS is Windows 10.

I know that this may well be hardware issues, but I would like to know if and how I can find more details in the logs, etc...

The System logs basically show nothing useful, after the reboot, there is a kernel power error, but the reason is unspecified (41). It seems like the system doesn't have the time to log the error before the power is lost.

I did `sfc /scannow` which was fine and the OS is basically new and so are the machines.

Are there more detailed logs that I'm missing? And can I maybe increase the verbosity somewhere in order to debug this properly? Or can I set up a monitor application that may get me some useful data?

Sadly I can't extract a lot of information or easily reproduce the error at this point.

Comment: Can you edit your question and elaborate on the details of the work stations and how old they are?

Comment: @Halfgaar well I don't have them at disposal right now, but they are new (as I mentioned) and the OS was cloned on them by a reseller and mid to low specs. I can elaborate next time, I have access to them.

Comment: If they are new, can you ask the manufacturer or seller for support?

Comment: @Halfgaar that may be the best solution, but at this point I'm attempting to eliminate possible OS/software faults before "playing the warranty card". Any ideas how to get more verbosity out of the crash/the error logs?I'll try to boot them on Linux and see if they behave the same way. In that case, it should be a hardware issue.

Comment: There are a fair amount of bootable diagnostic tools. The ultimate boot CD has a bunch for instance. They can do various stress tests.

Comment: @Halfgaar thanks, I'll try that. I forgot to mention that I did some stress testing on windows, but it didn't lead to a crash. I.e. the crash doesn't seem to be induced by adding more load.